# Forcing a specific collection to be used in the whole code base for certain objects

Tags: scala, coding-style

I have a class defined as such:

```scala
trait Column {
  def att1: String
  def att2: String = "b"
}

object Column {
  def apply(name: String): Column =
    new Column {
      override val att1: String = att1
    }
}
```

And pretty much everywhere in my code base it's being used as a collection: `Seq[Column]`.

I would like to enforce that every class who uses multiple `Column` must use `Seq` and not `Set` for example. The reason for this is because I just had to change `Set` to `Seq` everywhere in the code base and that took some time.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: This sounds impossible. Maybe create a type alias or a wrapper? But you can't forbid some code to create `Seq[Column]` at some point.

Comment: I guess I could make Column private or protected to the package and then expose a `Columns` class or something like that. But assuming that the development team will only use the `Columns` class (even if in principle they could use `Column`), I was wondering what an elegant solution for this would be.

Comment: Not sure if a **Scalafix** custom rule could help with this.